# Simple buck circuit reducing 240V AC to around 5V at 300mA

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, mains, esp8266

I work with a lot of ESP8266 microcontrollers, and often need to power them from 240V AC mains. This generally involves either a wall-wart or a dedicated isolated module such as the [HLK-PM03](http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=59).

However, it occurred to me that - in situations where isolation from the mains supply is not a requirement - I could maybe use a simple buck circuit.¹

I came up with [this circuit](http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3Z5OfATOALNVBmArAGw44DsekJGeqeAHCBjiHgzgFABuIAtGBhiFQZIPPgLFRwzETRFyo0PGwAmo-pgHcM9CemUBTAGYBDAK4AbAC4qe2wcLUChMkAZMXrAJ1v1n4MOh+IrTYbOb+6LqQOupy0AEKQmAAnHj8kDiQqGA4yQQBbGB4yeAEGhHlMiKIKPBsAMaC0eWozUEKaCnJ3T29PfQEillgtLTJfLmQdEwwCGwA7k2+DmAJQWw4AgBe+gB2+p7cJRBg0CQT1LQpqFdo+twkkqiwtSi0AsdsW4Kj9jK-uhAO32h2SCyWfx+yzkbAA5lDITdfCR0DCcAR6IxIuptNVYlA2N4sZDiRIqhsSFUYk4AeoIDCAEogAjiAgiFngZKowQgWhwZiSOJTGyrQIrBKAtxmKw2XjqPxaak8qUeWV2BUSSVGaXWUgiRXlMBlTWC8HEvxIyGQcGWiSk2JsAAeIBwtEiyUxYEerQgrJAABkAPbGZRsQPgAYCar4L1MI1xeguEYusPgJgckTCboMarQY08nIp8PsqMMRBMHCtBS+HkidhAA):

[image: circuit]

The resulting 6V-or-so could then be passed through an LDO to produce a stable 3.3V supply.

Assuming I use a 250V-rated triac to chop the mains supply into pieces, is there any good reason this circuit wouldn't work and/or be unsafe?²

In addition, would I need to use an inductor and capacitor rated for 250V? Under normal circumstances, they would spend most of their time seeing low voltage.

---

¹ I toyed with the idea of capacitive droppers, but the current requirements of the ESP8266 are too high for that to be feasible.

² I am well aware of the importance of isolation, thank you. This is for use in situations where mains-referenced power is not a concern.

Comment: How are you generating your triac drive signal? How does the feedback work?

Comment: Why would mains isolation not be an issue?  Stuff that runs on 5V won't survive even a little boop of 120V.  Even if there's no human risk, troubleshooting and replacing burnt out components sucks compared to the cost of isolation.  The microcontrollers and labor are so cheap you just don't care?

Comment: By the time you get it to work you will have spent more time and money than you would on using someone's off-line supply chip.  And for that much of a step-down ratio, you want to use a flyback transformer, so isolation comes for free.  Essentially, you'll be building your own wall-wart.

Comment: @BeB00 any output voltage between 5V and 15V is acceptable, so I hoped I could just adjust it once and have it run without feedback. Plus there's a zener to cap the voltage. Would it really drift so far as to kill the zener?

Comment: @KH Mains isolation is to protect humans, not the circuitry. What you're talking about there isn't isolation.

Comment: @TimWescott granted a transformer is certainly a *better* way to do it. But I'm not trying to do it better, I'm trying to do it cheap and small.

Comment: If you're making a bunch of boards, using a conventional solution might well be better and cheaper.

Comment: @KH you may be right. But I was trying to come up with a physically smaller solution. I don't like that the HLK module takes up more space than the entire rest of my circuit. If I could buy (cheaply) a module half the size of the HLK, that would be ideal. But I haven't found one.

Comment: How much cubic volume are you talking about?  One of those potted bricks about 2/3 the size of a banana?  You're not likely to do better or cheaper than a USB power cube, and some of those don't even perform very well.  If you're planning to use a low drop out for 325mA load, you should double check your power consumption on the low drop out for the full range of voltage you might provide.

Comment: There are chips especially for this purpose. They can be found in the cheapy wifi light bulbs.

Comment: There are too many reasons why this circuit won't work or be practical.  Too unstable, acting as a 5% duty cycle 350Vp AC switch into a very large inductor on the verge of melting the Zener is unregulated and very expensive

Comment: @Kartman that is a very good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *is there any good reason this circuit wouldn't work and/or be unsafe?*

There are a few designs that can do this but I wouldn't recommend a triac type because of peak currents into the 120 mH inductor and the sheer physical size needed for the 120 mH inductor: -

[image]

The above regulates to 5 volts DC from an AC voltage range of 85 volts to 265 volts. It can probably be coerced into producing 3.3 volts directly too. The source is [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00286922-stevalisa178v1-5-v1-w-30-khz-buck-demo-with-viper01-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Then there is this from Power Integrations: -

[image]

Source information [here](https://ac-dc.power.com/design-support/reference-designs/design-examples/rdr-737-1pt44watt-non-isolated-buck-converter-using-linkswitch-tn2-900v/).

These are the preferred methods for non-isolated buck converters and note how much smaller the inductor needs to be in these designs.

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{These designs are dangerous in that they don't isolate high voltage mains}}}$$

The preferred method is to use a flyback design not only because the circuit provides inherent isolation properties but, because a step down transformer can deliver much more current to the output for a given (small) transformer size: -

[image]

Circuit from [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/328/rdr-736_7watt_wide_range_input_dual_output_non_iso-1880725.pdf) and note the construction size: -

[image]

Pretty much all the space above would be taken up by a suitably dimensioned 120 mH in the OP design.

$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\text{There is very little sense in not using an isolating flyback design}}}$$